# using AJAX with a loop

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am having problems with an AJAX function I am working on.

The function is supposed to insert some information into a DB. The problem comes when I put the whole AJAX code inside a loop, because it crashes. Here is an example of a code which is similar to what I am doing:

```
function funcionDePrueba() {
    var url = 'aaajax.py'
    var x = 3
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        xmlhttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
        if (!xmlhttp) {
            alert("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
            return;
        }
        var xml = xmlhttp;
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xml.readyState == 4) {
                alert(claveProyecto);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to put the whole AJAX code inside a `for` loop?

Comment: Please elaborate on "it crashes".  What is the exception raised? Describing raised exceptions as "an error" and "a crash" without further info is not adequate for a software developer, especially one asking for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, it is possible.

**But**; In the provided snippet you have a `return` statement inside your `for`-loop. This will make the loop have one go and then return from the function. If you'd like it do to more than one iteration, remove the statement: `return true`.

Comment: THANKS, that is actualy the problem! only other question, Do I have to place the return outside the for? or Can I just ignore that and dont place it anywhere?

Comment: @mauguerra If the function isn't supposed to return anything you can ignore it all together. (ie. if you don't need to return anything, don't).

Comment: If you ommit the `return` statement, your function will return `undefined`. Which is fine, because you're not expecting a return value.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to refp's answer, I'd like to point out the following:

You're not declaring `i` or `xmlhttp` as `var`s before assigning values to them. If you don't declare a `var`, it is scoped as a global variable (on the `window` object). This is most likely **not** what you're trying to do, because it means that both `i` and `xmlhttp` will be available *outside* your function, after it was called.

This is probably what you want to do:

```
function funcionDePrueba(iterations) {
    var url = 'aaajax.py';
    var xmlhttp;
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        // [...]
    }
}
```

Note the `var` declarations for `xmlhttp` and for `i`. Also, hardcoding `x` (the number of iterations) might not be a good idea. You make it an argument instead, as in the example above.